# Query to get two sample records for each id in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to get two sample records for each id in the table tb1. I tried with the below query but not getting the desired result.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
 Id,
 DateTime
FROM (
  SELECT
   Id,DateTime,RAND() AS rnd,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DateTime ORDER BY rnd) AS pos
   FROM
    [proj:tb1.UtilDateTime] )
WHERE pos <= 2
ORDER BY VehicleId,DateTime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT
 Id,
 DateTime
FROM (
  SELECT
   Id,DateTime,RAND() AS rnd,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY rnd) AS pos
   FROM
    [proj:tb1.UtilDateTime] )
WHERE pos <= 2
ORDER BY Id,DateTime
```